# How can I do a sprite to jump with moveYModifier when I touch the screen

Tags: sprite, andengine

I'm still new with programming android. I have a problem with my game project. The problem is I have a problem with moveYModifier for sprite to jump when I touch the screen. Other problem is I got an error when I try to make a touch event method. Can somebody help me, so I can understand how to write correctly the method. I do not use engine extension  because I think it's enough by using moveYModifier. I already search the answer but I still confuse about it. Thanks.

here my code :

```
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.modifier.MoveYModifier;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.modifier.SequenceEntityModifier;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.IOnSceneTouchListener;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.AutoParallaxBackground;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.ParallaxBackground.ParallaxEntity;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.AnimatedSprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.anddev.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
import  org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TiledTextureRegion;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;

public class KetigaMainActivity extends BaseGameActivity implements IOnSceneTouchListener{
private int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private BitmapTextureAtlas bitmapTextureAtlas;
private TiledTextureRegion playerTextureRegion;

private BitmapTextureAtlas autoParallaxBackgroundTexture;

private TextureRegion parallaxLayerBack;
private TextureRegion parallaxLayerMid;
private TextureRegion parallaxLayerFront;
private TextureRegion parallaxLayerBackMid;
private int jumpHeight = 100;
private int jumpDuration = 2;

private int playerX = CAMERA_WIDTH/2;
private int playerY = CAMERA_HEIGHT - playerTextureRegion.getTileHeight() - (parallaxLayerFront.getHeight()/3);


@Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera));

}
@Override
public void onLoadResources(){

    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
    this.bitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
    this.playerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.bitmapTextureAtlas, this, "ulat10.png",0,0,4,2);
    this.autoParallaxBackgroundTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
    this.parallaxLayerFront = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.autoParallaxBackgroundTexture, this, "tanah6.png",0,810);
    this.parallaxLayerBack = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.autoParallaxBackgroundTexture, this, "background1.png",0,0);
    this.parallaxLayerBackMid = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.autoParallaxBackgroundTexture, this, "gunung3.png",0,490);
    this.parallaxLayerMid = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.autoParallaxBackgroundTexture, this, "awan5.png",0,700);
    this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTextures(this.bitmapTextureAtlas, this.autoParallaxBackgroundTexture);
}
@Override
public Scene onLoadScene(){
    new Scene();
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    final Scene scene = new Scene();
    final AutoParallaxBackground autoParallaxBackground = new AutoParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0, 5);
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.parallaxLayerBack.getHeight(), this.parallaxLayerBack)));
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-1/4.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.parallaxLayerBackMid.getHeight() - (parallaxLayerFront.getHeight()/6), this.parallaxLayerBackMid)));
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-1/2.0f, new Sprite(0, 0,this.parallaxLayerMid)));
    autoParallaxBackground.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(-3.0f, new Sprite(0, CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.parallaxLayerFront.getHeight(), this.parallaxLayerFront)));
    scene.setBackground(autoParallaxBackground);

    AnimatedSprite player = new AnimatedSprite(playerX, playerY, this.playerTextureRegion);
    player.setScaleCenterY(this.playerTextureRegion.getTileHeight());
    player.animate(new long[]{100, 100, 100},0 ,2, true);
    scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);

    scene.attachChild(player);



    return scene;
}
@Override   
public void onLoadComplete(){
}   
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
        jump(); // this where I got an error
    }
    return false;   
}
public boolean jump(AnimatedSprite player){

final MoveYModifier moveUpModifier = new MoveYModifier(jumpDuration  /2, playerY,   playerY + jumpHeight);
    final MoveYModifier moveDownModivier = new MoveYModifier(jumpDuration  /2, playerY + jumpHeight, playerY );
    final SequenceEntityModifier modifier = new         SequenceEntityModifier(moveUpModifier, moveDownModivier);
    player.registerEntityModifier(new SequenceEntityModifier (modifier));

    return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) 
{
    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) 
    {
        jump(player); 
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: I already did like what you wrote above (jump(player)) but unfortunately error is still appear. It is maybe because I'm failed to register the entity modifier or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JumpModifier instead

```
 public boolean jump(AnimatedSprite player){
        //your innitial y-position
        final float innitialYPosition = 120;

        //-140 means jump upward, positive move downward
        JumpModifier jumpModifier = new JumpModifier(1, fromX, toX, fromY, toY, -140, new IEntityModifier.IEntityModifierListener() {
            @Override
            public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
                animatedSprite.stopAnimation(0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier, IEntity pItem) {
                animatedSprite.animate(50);
                animatedSprite.setY(innitialYPosition);
            }
        });

        animatedSprite.registerEntityModifier(jumpModifier);
    }
```